# Catch a specific exception by its name cpp

Tags: c++, exception

I use pcl 1.7 [tracking code](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/tracking.php) and In some cases this method:

```
tracker_->compute ();
```

Gives me these errors:

> [pcl::ApproxNearestPairPointCloudCoherence::initCompute] PointCloudCoherence::Init failed.
>       [pcl::ApproxNearestPairPointCloudCoherence::compute] Init failed.

I now know that error is thrown and I would like to catch exactly this error to tell the program what to do if this error occurs. I tried like this:

```
  try
  {
    tracker_->compute ();
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    std::cout<<"inside the exception"<<std::endl;
  }
```

To catch all the errors but it did not work..... And also with

```
catch(pcl::ApproxNearestPairPointCloudCoherenceException &e)
```

my program did not even compile....

So any ideas what I do wrong?

Comment: Does it throw any exception? These messages are not really looking like unhandled exception. And for the second try, you probably forgot an include which defines `pcl::ApproxNearestPairPointCloudCoherenceException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I browsed [the source](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl) in order to look for the location where the error is raised, and [found out](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/search?q=[pcl::ApproxNearestPairPointCloudCoherence::initCompute]+PointCloudCoherence::Init+failed.&unscoped_q=[pcl::ApproxNearestPairPointCloudCoherence::initCompute]+PointCloudCoherence::Init+failed.) that in your specific case it is raised by

```
if (!PointCloudCoherence<PointInT>::initCompute ())
{
    PCL_ERROR ("[pcl::%s::initCompute] PointCloudCoherence::Init failed.\n", getClassName().c_str());
    return (false);
}
```

so you see, there is no `throw xxx` here but only a **macro** which hides the actual error handling from us.

---

To find out what exactly was happening, I then searched for a definition of `PCL_ERROR` and the search yielded that it is defined in the file [`print.h`](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/common/include/pcl/console/print.h) as

```
#define PCL_ERROR(...)   pcl::console::print (pcl::console::L_ERROR, __VA_ARGS__)
```

with `pcl::console::print` being a function simply ***printing*** the error, not **throwing** an exception.

---

So, you **cannot catch the error because it is not an exception**, but rather only plain text written to the console.

Comment: Ok I got the problem now, but nevertheless I would like to handle it if this errror message is printed. So I tired:                                                                                      if (!tracker_->getCloudCoherence::initCompute())
  {
    tracker_->compute ();
  }
 But this gives me an error:  ‘getCloudCoherence’ is not a class or namespace